# Two war files deployed in same docker container is not accessible

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, deployment, dockerfile

I have deployed two war file in docker container, say app1.war and app2.war. app1.war is calling internally app2.war to access few services. I am able to access service in app1.war from browser and internally when app1.war tries to call service in app2.war I am getting following error

I am using Apache server and each request will be first hit to apache server and then directed to the services running in container. Apache server is running in my host as a service.

I have created Dockerfile by taking tomcat as base and copied app1.war and app2.war in webapps folder and expose port is 8080

and build image as
docker build -t myapp .

execute it as
docker run -it -p 9999:8080 myapp

http://localhost:9999/app1/service1 ----- this is accessible and this URL is internally calling a service which is deployed in app2 http://localhost:9999/app2/calculation

on hitting *http://localhost:9999/app2/calculation* URL I am getting below error

```
Connection error for URL[http://localhost/app2/calculation/]. Exception: [I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost/app2/calculation/": Connect to localhost:80 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:80 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)].
```

I am looking for a solution for this issues and want to know where exactly the issue is. Any response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your app2 deployed on Tomcat is exposed on port 8080 within the container, not 9999. Therefore, you're getting error when trying to access it on port 9999 from within the container. If you change internal endpoint to 8080 for app2, it should work.

Now, deploying 2 war files on the same Tomcat like this is actually an anti-pattern in containerized world. The usual architecture would be to have 2 separate images/containers, each having its own war file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. both war file app1.war and app2.war is deployed in same container, tomcat in container running on 8080 but it is published on 9999 port, so outside its accessible from 9999 port and since its redirected through Apache server so I can not give container port. 
I agree on second point we are trying in parallel but trying above scenario. Please suggest what is happening wrong here

Comment: Communication from one war to the other is happening within your container, not through Apache. Port 9999 is only exposed externally to the container, not within the container - this is what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks teleodor, I forget to update when I am trying to access app2.war with exposed port then its working but not working through Apache server .. anyways thanks for your valuable input